# What is difference between analog and digital input and output, and when should i use anlog or digital (input or output)?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, electronics

How should i determine whether to use input as analog or digital and same for output too?

Comment: This question is too general. Rather mention the specific problem you want to solve, in which you cannot find a way to decide between analog Vs. digital.

Comment: I am making an line follower robot so i am unable to understand  what to use analog or digital pins.

Comment: You also need to specify what sensors you are using for your line following robot.

Comment: Array of 6 infrared sensor

Comment: There must be over 10000 different sensors of this kind. Put exact references please. References will lead you to datasheets, datasheets will lead you to the solution: either they provide an analog signal or a digital one!

Comment: Well all i know that this sensor have 12 pins for output, 6 for digital and 6 for analog.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you don't know enough to build your robot. You have a lot to learn first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will use digital pin modes when dealing with signals that are either "on" or "off", such as an LED, a switch, or another digital IC.

Analog inputs are used when you want to read the voltage potential of something. This is typically used to read analog sensors. Analog outputs are not really analog at all on the Arduino. Instead, the Arduino uses [something called PWM](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pulse-width-modulation) to create a pseudo-analog signal.

You can read more about analog and digital here:
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/analog-vs-digital

Comment: Is it same for output too

Comment: For digital? Yes. Digital input and output are the same. Analog input is different from analog output. Analog in uses special hardware to determine a the voltage on the pin, while analog output uses PWM to mimic a voltage on the pin, but it is not truly analog out.

Comment: Also note that the analog pins can also be used as digital input and digital outputs. In case you run out of pins.